How to use JS in Bootstrap?
Hi I want to learn webjars. So i added this dependences to my Gradle project:
implementation group: 'org.webjars', name: 'webjars-locator', version: '0.52'
implementation group: 'org.webjars', name: 'bootstrap', version: '5.3.3'
implementation group: 'org.webjars.bower', name: 'jquery', version: '3.7.1'

I want to create a drop-down menu for changing the language. I want to add it to the header. Here's the HTML I wrote:
Register page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #252d36;">
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

    <div th:replace="~{layouts/header :: header}"></div>

    <div th:replace="~{register/user/reg-user-form :: reg-user-form}"></div>
</body>

Header
<header xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"
        th:fragment="header"
        class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-md-between py-3 mb-4 border-bottom bg-dark navbar-dark">

    <div class="col-md-3 mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <a href="/" class="d-inline-flex link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none">
            <p class="navbar-brand mx-3 h4" aria-label="Bootstrap">Planning Poker</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
        <li><a href="/" class="nav-link px-2 text-light">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-light">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-light">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-light">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-light">About</a></li>

        <!-- Language link -->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="langDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Select Language
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="langDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item changeLang" data-lang="en" th:text="#{messages.templates.header.lang.eng}">EN</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item changeLang" data-lang="swe" th:text="#{messages.templates.header.lang.swe}">SWE</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item changeLang" data-lang="uk" th:text="#{messages.templates.header.lang.uk}">UK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-end">
        <a href="/login" class="btn btn-outline-light me-2">Login</a>
        <a href="/register/user" class="btn btn-light me-2">Sign-up</a>
    </div>
</header>

The button with changing text appears, but when clicked, nothing happens. Although I expect the menu to open where I can select the language. That's why I think the issue is that the JavaScript is not working.
I also tried taking the dropdown menu from the official website, but the situation is the same.
I tried changing the links for the JS by adding the version to them. However, I assume this is not necessary if I am using 'webjars-locator'.
I don't understand what i did wrong.

Are there any errors in your dev console?

@mykaf No, all clear

try attribute data-bs-toggle="dropdown" instead of the older data-toggle

@ITgoldman No luck, same thing

Again, I think data-bs-toggle is the issue, in this example it works.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Dropdown Toggle Example</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="p-3">

<header xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"
        th:fragment="header"
        class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-md-between py-3 mb-4 border-bottom bg-dark navbar-dark">

    <div class="col-md-3 mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <a href="/" class="d-inline-flex link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none">
            <p class="navbar-brand mx-3 h4" aria-label="Bootstrap">Planning Poker</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
        <li><a href="/" class="nav-link px-2 text-light">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-light">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-light">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-light">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-light">About</a></li>

        <!-- Language link -->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="langDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Select Language
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="langDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item changeLang" data-lang="en" th:text="#{messages.templates.header.lang.eng}">EN</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item changeLang" data-lang="swe" th:text="#{messages.templates.header.lang.swe}">SWE</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item changeLang" data-lang="uk" th:text="#{messages.templates.header.lang.uk}">UK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-end">
        <a href="/login" class="btn btn-outline-light me-2">Login</a>
        <a href="/register/user" class="btn btn-light me-2">Sign-up</a>
    </div>
</header>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown Button
            </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  <!-- Bootstrap 5 JS Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




Thank you, yes, that's one of the reasons, but I also had to add
<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js}"></script> in the header.
